# Return trip mandatory when leaving Australia?

Tags: planning, australia, no-advance-plans

Is it mandatory to plan the return trip in advance when leaving Australia (NSW) for 3 months?
I ask because airport staff makes it look like there's a law or something without explaining further details.

If so, why, and how can you be exempt from this regulation?

Edit:
Trip is to Germany.

Edit:
As comments and replies suggest this is the wrong question.  I explained the details in the comments myself.  The whole situation has been miscommunicated to me.

Comment: Can you clarify this at all? I'm an Australian and it just doesn't make sense to me. Heaps of Aussies go off travelling for indefinite periods of time starting with a one-way ticket and return only a few years later. Haven't done it yet myself though.

Comment: Are you Australian or not? Often having a return trip is mandatory to *enter* a country that you're not a permanent resident of, but not to leave one.

Comment: I think you're either confusing with the fact that when visiting Australia (depending on your nationality) you might be allowed to stay for 3 months and might have to prove that you have a return ticket or an onward ticket to show that you don't intend to stay in Australia as an illegal immigrant. Most countries have such rules.

Comment: Oh sorry, seems someone gave me the wrong info.  Proof-of-onward travel is not required by Australia but of some countries neighbouring the EU countries and it's the airport staff's duty to check that beforehand.
I'm sorry but this was completely miscommunicated to me, so can I close this question as invalid?

Comment: @Gilles: Exactly the problem here, and furtherly it's the airport's duty to check that.

Comment: I think some countries have been trying to get the airports or the airlines to check this stuff when people board flights, but I can't remember anybody checking me for this... then again I've always had return tickets so far...

Comment: hroptatyr: Not airport staff, but airline AFAIK. @hippietrail It's pretty general, and it's the airlines (at least, if you're denied entry because of these checks, I think the burden would be on them to carry you back). If you always had return tickets they'd know already.

Comment: I think it depends on the country you're leaving from, the country you're going to, and other stuff too. The only time I had this that I can recall was flying to the US from Canada many years ago.

Comment: I've voted to close this question since it turned out to be based on a false premise.

Comment: Maybe instead of closing the question we will edit it to represent the real situation? The information can still help others.

Comment: When I was flying from Australia to New Zealand the airline (and later immigration) wanted to see a ticket out of NZ. You might want to check if the EU/Germany require that.

Comment: I think rewording the question to be anything of use will actually turn it into another, different, question. Closing isn't punishment. If there is another different question worth asking I would ask it as a fresh question.

Comment: Closed as per discussion above.

Answer (score 1):

3 months (90 days, to be exact) is the period for which a citizen of a visa-exempt country such as Australia is allowed to stay in the EU (the Schenge area, to be exact) without a visa.

If you want to stay longer, [you need a long-stay visa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_in_the_European_Union#Stays_exceeding_three_months) (and a residence permit if it's longer than a year).